# Trouble Using Third Party Framework In Xcode 3.2

Tags: xcode, oauth, frameworks

I am attempting to set up my own project using a third party library (MPOAuthConnection) for connecting to an oauth REST API.

Steps I've gone through thus far:

1. Downloaded source for MPOAuthConnection.
2. Built source and had a resulting MPOAuth.framework in the Product tab.
3. Opened my existing project and dragged the MPOAuth.framework into the "Linked Frameworks" of my project.
4. Build my project and it fails at Runtime with the following error

> [Session started at 2009-11-03
>   16:41:37 -0600.]
>  Warning - No
>   location found for
>   "OAuthClientController.m:68"
>  GNU
>   gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version
>   gdb-1344) (Fri Jul  3 01:19:56 UTC
>   2009)
>  Copyright 2004 Free Software
>   Foundation, Inc.
>  GDB is free
>   software, covered by the GNU General
>   Public License, and you are
>   welcome to change it and/or distribute
>   copies of it under certain
>   conditions.
>  Type "show copying" to
>   see the conditions.
>  There is
>   absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type
>   "show warranty" for details.
>  This
>   GDB was configured as
>   "x86_64-apple-darwin".tty
>   /dev/ttys002
>  Loading program into
>   debugger…
>  sharedlibrary
>   apply-load-rules all
>  warning:
>   Unable to read symbols for
>   
> "@executable_path/../Frameworks/MPOAuth.framework/Versions/A/MPOAuth"
>   (file not found).
>  warning: Unable
>   to read symbols from "MPOAuth" (not
>   yet mapped into memory).
>  Program
>   loaded.
>  run
>  [Switching to
>   process 32686]
>  Running…
>  dyld:
>   Library not loaded:
>   
> @executable_path/../Frameworks/MPOAuth.framework/Versions/A/MPOAuth
>   Referenced from:
>   
> /Users/markpowell/Documents/Programming/Cocoa/Celery/build/Debug/Celery.app/Contents/MacOS/Celery
>   Reason: image not found
>  No memory
>   available to program now: unsafe to
>   call malloc
>  Data Formatters
>   temporarily unavailable, will re-try
>   after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call
>   dlopen at this time.)

So apparently, it can't find any of the framework information at runtime, but can at compile time? I'm a bit new to the OS X platform, so still struggling a bit with the tools. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I did add a new Build Phase -> New Copy Files Build phase, dragged the Framework (MPOAuth.framework) to the dialog and set it to go to Frameworks. But still got the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you haven't copied the MPOAuth framework into your application bundle:

"@executable_path/../Frameworks/MPOAuth.framework/Versions/A/MPOAuth" (file not found).

The @exectuable_path is the path to your application binary inside of ".../MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS"

You should create a new build phase for your target, "Copy Files Phase" that specifies the destination as "Frameworks". Drag the MPOAuth framework in your Xcode project into that path and it will be copied into the correct location.

**EDIT Nov 3rd, 2009: 17:59 EST**: I would highly suggest reading the Xcode documentation as it saved me a ton of time when I learned how to use this tool effectively. Select "Xcode Help" from the "Help" menu while Xcode is active.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it is time to dig deeper into the help text. I did create the new build phase, but without any luck. Which implies that the copy of the files didn't work as expected...

Comment: Thank you, further upon further inspection, I failed to drag the actual framework under the copy build phase.