# How can i add third party framework to my cocoa project

Tags: cocoa, macos, frameworks

I want to add third party framework "log4Cocoa" to my cocoa application. I followed the steps to add the framework and created "Copy Files" phase as well. Project is getting build without any error. Problem occurs when i try to run the application i get error saying "Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'."

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: “Data Formatters temporarily unavailable” is from the debugger. Please edit your question to include the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the framework opensource? I do not think it has to do with you, more with how you are using its services or maybe the framework is broken. Contact the developer he might be able to help you with it.

Edit:
[Trouble Using Third Party Framework In Xcode 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670672/trouble-using-third-party-framework-in-xcode-3-2)

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to add a framework ( like adding jars in java ) . It depends on the framework .
For example look at 320  instructions

http://github.com/facebook/three20